# How to set custom price format for woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, decimal, price

Hi I have problem with woocommerce decimal, i need to display the price with the following format:

- 0.1
- 0.10
- 0.100

After a lot of research i found this code but was not working correctly!

```
add_filter( 'formatted_woocommerce_price', 'wc_custom_price_format', 10, 5 );

function wc_custom_price_format( $number_format, $price, $decimals, $decimal_separator, $thousand_separator){

$lastnum = $number_format[strlen($number_format)-1];

if ($lastnum <= 0):

   return substr($number_format, 0, -2);
    
elseif ($lastnum == 0):

   return substr($number_format, 0, -1);

else:

    return $number_format;


endif;

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

add_filter( 'formatted_woocommerce_price', 'ts_woo_decimal_price', 10, 5 );
function ts_woo_decimal_price( $formatted_price, $price, $decimal_places, $decimal_separator, $thousand_separator ) {
    $unit = number_format( intval( $price ), 0, $decimal_separator, $thousand_separator );
    $decimal = sprintf( '%02d', ( $price - intval( $price ) ) * 100 );
    return $unit . '' . $decimal_separator. $decimal . '';
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I set 0.1 but it display 0.10, the problem is that i need to display the price in different formats as follow: 0.1 / 0.10 / 0.100, without any auto changes, Like this: 0.1=0.1, 0.10=0.10, 0.100=0.100

Comment: I have one question ?
How to enter the price in back-end product page?
Possible to sent to reply screenshot ?

Thanks

Comment: please take a look of the screenshot